# using oracle sql, how to get a specific word(table1) and put it to another field

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I am trying to manipulate a full address, Basically I need to get the cities from table1 and retain the rest of the strings from the address.

TABLE1 [image: TABLE1 LIST OF CITIES]

SAMPLE [image: SAMPLE]

RESULT [image: RESULT]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because has no efforts, and images added rather than text data which preferable to debug the test case.

Comment: Likewise. Describe table (ddl) and provide sample data - **as text**. Plus show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify which cities are mentioned in the address using `join`:

```
select a.*, c.city
from addr a left join
     city c
     on a.addr like '%' || c.city || '%';
```

Do note, however, that this could match other parts of the address.  So `'New York'` would match `'New York Avenue'`.  If you have additional rules, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, being clear about exactly what you want to do.